# AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator doesn't work

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable, animatedvectordrawable

I want to control animation while playing, So I used object animator. below code doesn't play animation at all to control.

```
 ObjectAnimator anim1 = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.upload_arrow_fill);
    AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animSet.play(anim1);
    animSet.setDuration(1000);
    animSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animSet.start();
```

XML:

```
<objectAnimator
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:propertyName="pathData"
android:repeatCount="-1"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:valueFrom="M21 32 L35 32 L35 32 L21 32 Z"
android:valueTo="M21 10 L35 10 L35 32 L21 32 Z"
android:valueType="pathType"
android:startOffset="300"
android:duration="1200"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in" />
```

it doesn't do anything, what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Any solution for this?